# Xamarin iOS build server on OSX using Jenkins and Nuget

Tags: ios, jenkins, xamarin, nuget

I am currently building a continuous integration pipeline on an iMac in order to build Xamarin iOS apps. We are using Jenkins to control the CI build process but the project contains a number of Nuget packages that are not stored in our Git source repo. As these packages are not downloaded by Jenkins I need to call a Restore on the solution.

Is Nuget.exe installed as part of Xamarin Studio on OSX (and if so where) and if not is there an OSX command line version for El Capitan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mono installer on OS-X supplies a nuget shell script and the `nuget.exe` CIL-assembly

### Default install location of script:

```
/usr/local/bin/nuget
```

### Script contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.0/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.0/lib/mono/nuget/NuGet.exe "$@"
```

### Nuget version:

As of Mono 4.4.0, the nuget version is:

```
NuGet Version: 2.8.5.0
```

### Nuget restore:

In the root of your solution, all you have to do is call `nuget restore` with your solution, i.e.

```
>nuget restore mysolution.sln

All packages listed in packages.config are already installed
```